# Looping for a file in a folder and get file name

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

can someone explain to me why this does not work.

```
FOR %%G IN (C:\) do echo %~nG
```

According to documents.. %~nG should get the file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in a batch file, you'd need `%%~nG`.

If it's being executed directly from the prompt, you'd need `FOR %G ...`

Either way, you'd need to add a filemask `c:\*`